# Wordpress site getting 404 if "Permalink" option set to "Post name"

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a rather strange issue with my website.  I have just decided to remove my website from one server to a new server (I no longer wanted to use wpengine.co.uk)

I have now got the site up and running however the only issue I have is if I set the "permalinks" option to "post name" as can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Fo2.png then I get a 404.

I have the following Apache setup on a Linux box:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess looks like this (for now I have set the file permissions to 666):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Lastly I have enabled as can be seen from my "phpinfo()" page. [image: Mod Rewrite]

The site does work if I use the ugly looking "plain" option... but that is obviously something I don't want.

Comment: Did you try to go to settings -> permalinks and just click save?

Comment: Yes, I did that too.

Comment: i hate to bring up one of the obvious, but more times then not, disabling all of the plugins and using a default theme tends to proove your database and wordpress install are working correctly. From there activate your then and then the plugins one at a time to see if one of them is causing an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did that (deactivated every single plugin which made the site look rather bad, haha) but sadly even the simplest of pages /contact-us/ gave a 404

Answer (score 0):

Reboot Apache after making changes to httpd.config. (Changes to pph.ini and .htaccess don't require reboots).

And, you may need to add `AllowOverride All` for the document root:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    # ... other directives...
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Comment: You shouldn't change httpd.config (or in my case the file apache2.conf) as it loads some good basic settings.  If you want to override those values you should add them to the actual vhost itself (in my case located at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-website.conf) This step has also already been done.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your .htaccess file from wordpress root directory, then try to change permalink setting.

**Note** :- backup .htaccess file before delete it.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I've done that but it didn't help.  WordPress did indeed have access to update the .htaccess file (it currently has 666 file permission... just in case)  This is a really strange issue :-/

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer turned out to be rather strange.  It appears that for this to work I needed to install some extra PHP extensions.  All I needed to do was:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

Although I think that the one that finally worked was:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

I saw warnings about this but I had no idea that that would actually stop WordPress's redirection.  If somebody knows why this is the case I'd be really grateful to know.